# BLE Restricted Access

Tags: security, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have designed a BLE peripheral into a product.  There will be an app developed (Android, Windows) but for now I am writing firmware to support the app in the blind.

We cannot have someone access the peripheral who is not authorized.  To handle this I have a password stored in firmware.

There are seven custom characteristics, all but three of which are disabled upon initial connection.  The password characteristic is write only of course, once the correct password is sent the other characteristics are enabled.

I have no experience with BLE until now so I have no idea if this scheme is reasonable or not.

Is there a bettor way to limit access?

Thanks

Rich

Comment: Who do you consider authorized to access the peripheral? Will you store this password anywhere outside the peripheral (in the app for instance)? If you mean "I only want my app to access the peripheral," that's impossible if you're going to ship your app and peripheral to random users. If you mean "I only want specific people to access the peripheral," or if you have very careful controls around who has access to the app, that can have solutions.

Comment: Having the password on the firmware can be problematic. The same password for every device will only work until someone dumps the firmware. One password for each device will be a logistic nightmare.

Comment: Each device will have default password and a user password.  The default is permanent, assigned at the final tester and printed on the product label.  Users will use the app to access the device but will need the password specific for that device or their own if the previously set it.

Comment: You should write more about your security goals, like if you want to protect a human from accessing it by his phone or you want to protect an app from accessing it while allowing another on the same phone. Also what about man-in-the-middle attacks and eavesdropability? Note that a BLE peripheral can be accessed from multiple apps simultaneously on Android, iOS and Windows, so if you "enable" one characteristic by sending some Write from one app, another app can then access it since the peripheral don't see where a request originates from.

Comment: Emil,  I thought BLE only allowed one connection at a time...  I am not worried about man-in-the-middle as the app is used to configure these devices and maybe check their operation very infrequently.  These are HVAC control devices, the idea of security is to prevent tampering only..

Comment: Bluetooth 4.0 restricts maximum physical connections to 1 for peripherals. That restriction was however lifted in later version. However, the thing Android/iOS/Windows do has nothing to do with physical connections. They just allow multiple apps on the same phone access the link to a connected peripheral.

Comment: Instead of a fixed password, you may want to have a password that's generated based on the serial number or bluetooth address (something unique to each device, but static).  That way if someone got the password for one device it would only be good for that one device.

Comment: The above commentary is shockingly misinformed, especially the leading comment by @RobNapier. It absolutely *is* feasible – and, in fact, is mandatory in fields where privacy is paramount like biomedicine and pharmacotherapy – to restrict access of a BLE peripheral to a proprietary app under your control. The classic strategy is **dynamic encrypted challenge-response.** Once the peripheral has established an encrypted pairing with a possibly untrustworthy app, the peripheral challenges the app with a dynamic question; if the app sends an incorrect response, the peripheral forces disconnection.

Answer (score 0):

The Bluetooth standard defines the pairing/bonding concept with its corresponding encryption. Based on your specification it doesn't seem like it fits your needs.

You therefore have to come up with something on your own. How secure you make it is completely up to you. Your proposal is the simplest and most unsecure way of doing it. The most secure thing you can do is use some protocol created for these purposes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password-authenticated_key_agreement) to create a cryptographic key which you then use for authenticated encryption when you later communicate with your device. You decide which way you want to go based on the security level you want.

Comment: Thanks Emil, that is helpful.  We just need to prevent tampering, think of the locked cover over the thermostat in a high school.  I think our scheme will work but I wanted to make sure there wasn't a more obvious solution built into the standard.